# php reload page from ajax div

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I use a page with Jquery tabs and if i submit one of the forms in the tabs only that tab is submitted and refreshed with this jquery code:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#plaatsen_stap3", function(event) {
/* stop form from submitting normally */    

event.preventDefault();      
    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"../plaatsen_advertentie/plaatsen_advertentie_stap3.php",
      cache: false,                 
      data: $("#plaatsen_stap3").serialize(),
      success:function(data){
        $("#tab2").html(data);
      }     
    });
});
```

But in the case that there has to be payed i want to reload the page with the payment page. I want to do that AFTER the div is reloaded with the data, because i need to put a payment row in the DB with the data from the GET. Is location an option? If i use that now only the div (tab2) is loaded with the payment page....

So:
1.push submit
2.submit the form and load page/script in div by Ajax
3.check in php script (within the div) if payment is needed
4.if yes,add row with payment data in database and reload entire page with payment page (with some Get data in the url (last inserted id)

Comment: So you want the complete page to be refreshed to the payment page?

Comment: Could you re-word your question, what exactly is it you want to do??

Comment: pendo, yep thats wat i want!

Answer (score 0):

```
  success:function(data){
    $("#tab2").html(data);
    location.href = "/yourpage.php";
  }
```

Comment: i want to do it in the php script after the ajax reload, so this is not gonne work...

Comment: Did you try that code? If you haven't, try it first. You can't reload/redirect using php in this case because plaatsen_advertentie_stap3.php is executed asynchronously. Also, the php script of your initial page has been completely executed before the user even sees the page, so there is no chance of calling any function after that.

Comment: Hm. I don't understand. This IS done after the ajax-function? You could send the data to yourpage.php with JSON.

Comment: See the extra rules i added in the questionnaire

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanna do once the HTML is generated, give some time like about 5 seconds?

```
success:function(data){
    $("#tab2").html(data);
    setTimeout(function(){location.href = "/yourpage.php";}, 5000);
}
```

This would work for your use case. This cannot be done from server side.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. To rely on nr of seconds for achieving this?

Comment: Yeah, I agree... But cannot think of anything better than this.

Answer (score 0):

I think load() is what you are looking for. http://api.jquery.com/load/

The code below is intended as a guideline, and I'm not even sure it's working (I have not tested it). But I hope it will be of some help.

I would do something like this:

```
//Step 1
$(document).on("submit", "#plaatsen_stap3", function(event) {
/* stop form from submitting normally */    

event.preventDefault();      
    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"../plaatsen_advertentie/plaatsen_advertentie_stap3.php",
      cache: false,                 
      data: $("#plaatsen_stap3").serialize(),
      success:function(data){


   //Step 2 - submit the form and load page/script in div by Ajax 
   //Make sure array[] is an actual array that is sent to the test.php-script.
   $("#tab2").load("test.php", { 'array[]' , function() {
            //Step 3 - check in php script (within the div) if payment is needed (Do this from test.php - don't check the actual div but check values from array[])
            //Step 4 -  if yes,add row with payment data in database and reload entire page with payment page (with some Get data in the url (last inserted id)                     
            //Do this from test.php and use header-redirect to reload entire page   
           $("tab2").html(data); //Do this when test.php is loaded
       }

       } );


      }     
    });
});
```